# OSError: loadLibrary: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I tried a python code (Python 3.5.0) in Windows, it worked fine. When I tried the same code in Linux Ubuntu 16.04, it gave the following error:

> OSError: loadLibrary: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I even tried

> sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v

But, it gave the same error. All the required header files are in the same directory so does the code.
Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit to include either the script or a sample script showing the same issue?

Comment: Same error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481900/oserror-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-even-though-f)

Will this help ?